# Regex preg_match word

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to get a part of a string that starts with for example `Name:`. If the whole string looks like `Name: Carl`, I just want the `Carl` part and not the `Name:` prefix.

How can I do that? I have tried with:

```
$data = file_get_contents('page.html');
$regex = '/Name:.*/';
preg_match($regex,$data,$match);
var_dump($match);
```

But I get the output:

> array(1) { [0]=> string(28) "Name: Carl"

The other thing I don't understand is why the `array(1) { [0]=> string(28)` is showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your match line, do the following instead:

```
$regex = '/Name:(.*)/';
```

The matched portion (inside (.*)) will be in $match.

Answer (score 2):

You have to put what you want to retrieve in ():

```
'/Name:(.*)/i'
```

Comment: I upvoted because it's good to include the i in general, but it should be emphasized that this will make the match case insensitive -- on the off chance that this isn't what the OP wants.